# How to access nested data in D3js

Tags: arrays, object, d3.js, nested

I know it has been asked many times. I'll try all the solutions I found but I'm quite sure I miss somthing or, probably, i don't understand the how it works.

I'm trying to build cascading dropdown from aloaded json. here is the code I have build till now

```
    //retrieving alert data from db
const url_data = ("../../app/predictive/config/query.php");
var pred = d3.json(url_data).then(function(data) {
var dataset = d3.values(data);
  console.log(dataset);

//nesting the array by brand Key
  var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.brand; })
    .entries(dataset);
    console.log(nest)

//populate brand select from array
    var select = d3.select('#advertiser').selectAll('option')
    .data(nest).enter()
    select.append('option')
    .text(function(d, i) {
      return  '' + d.key + ''})
//appending attribute value to select option
    .attr("value", function (d, i) {
        return d.key;})

// var select2 = d3.select('#media').selectAll('option')
    var brand_sel = d3.select('select')
      .on("change",function(d){
      var selected = d3.select("#advertiser").node().value;
      console.log( selected );

//filter array on the first select
    var media =nest.filter(function(d) {
      return d.key == selected
      })
      console.log(media)

      var select2 = d3.select('#media').selectAll('option')
      .data(media)
      .enter()
      select2.append('option')
      .text(function(d, i) {
        return d.brand })
        console.log(select2)
});
})
```

now I have the first dropdown populated correctly but I'm unable to populate the second one. Here is the condole.log(media):

```
0:
 key: "APPLE"
    values: Array(2)
                 0:
                   id_alert: 2
                   advertiser: "Q8"
                   brand: "Q8 CARBURANTI"
                   first_seen_media: "italia 1"
                   first_seen: "2020-01-08"
                   last_seen: "2020-01-08"
                   media_type: "TV"
                   description: "none"
                 1:
                   id_alert: 3
                   advertiser: "Q8"
                   brand: "Q8 CARBURANTI"
                   first_seen_media: "other"
                   first_seen: "2020-01-10"
                   last_seen: "2020-01-10"
                   media_type: "DIGITAL"
                   description: "OTHER"
```

Within the select2 I obtain an empty dropdown instead of heaving the media_type filed

I hope someone can help me cause I read  a lot and my eyes says I find another way

As you may understand I'm qyuite new to D3 anf javascritp as well and I'm traying learning by doing

many thanks for any help

Comment: can yo post a snippet of what you want? that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: I have edited the question trying to better explain what I'm looking for. I'm not sure it will help, probably it is wrong but I'll try to asnwer in abetter way if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I got it, ieven if i believe it is not the best way to handle it.

here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body id="body">
    <div id="advertiser"><label class="select-label">Brand</label></div>
    <div id = "media"><label class="select-label">Media</label></div>
    <div id = "date"><label class="select-label">Start Date</label></div>
    <div id = "owner"><label class="select-label">Publisher</label></div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my d3js code

```
//retrieving alert data from db
const url_data = ("../../app/predictive/config/query.php");
var pred = d3.json(url_data).then(function(data) {
update(data)});
function update(d){


//nesting array for first select
var nest1 = d3.nest()
  .key(function(a) { return a.brand; })
  .key(function(d) { return d.media_type; })
  .key(function(d) { return d.first_seen; })
  .key(function(d) { return d.first_seen_media; })
  .entries(d)
  console.log(nest1);


var brand = d3.select("#advertiser")
    brand
    .append("select")
    .attr('class', "custom-select")
    .attr('id', 'brand')
    .selectAll("option")
    .data(nest1)
    .enter()
    .append("option")
    .attr("value", function(d){return d.key;})
    .text(function(d){return d.key;})



// identify the selected brand and store in slected var
//then filter by selection and then
//build the seconf nest

// brand  selection
var brand_sel = d3.select('select')
  .on("change",function(b){
  var selectedBrand = d3.select("#brand").node().value;
  console.log(selectedBrand)


//filter nest array by the selectred var on user first slection
var filteredMedia =nest1.filter(function(d) {
  return d.key == selectedBrand})[0]

//extract value of second nested array
var nest2 = filteredMedia.values;
//clean second media selection before appending the new selected media
var clean = d3.select("#media").selectAll("select").remove();


//create the secod select
var media = d3.select("#media")
    media
    .append("select")
    .attr('class', "custom-select")
    .attr('id', 'media_type')
    .selectAll("option")
    .data(nest2)
    .enter()
    .append("option")
    .attr("value", function(d){return d.key;})
    .text(function(d){return d.key;})

// media  selection
var selectedMedia = d3.select("#media_type").node().value;


//filter nest array by the selected var on user second slection
var filteredDate =nest2.filter(function(d) {
  return d.key == selectedMedia})[0]

  //extract value of second nested array
var nest3 = filteredDate.values;
//clean second media selection before appending the new selected media
var clean = d3.select("#date").selectAll("select").remove();

//create the secod select
var date = d3.select("#date")
    date
    .append("select")
    .attr('class', "custom-select")
    .attr('id', 'start_date')
    .selectAll("option")
    .data(nest3)
    .enter()
    .append("option")
    .attr("value", function(d){return d.key;})
    .text(function(d){return d.key;})



    // identify the selected date and store in slected var
    //then filter by selection and then
    //build the fourth nest

    // media  selection
    var selectedDate = d3.select("#start_date").node().value;


    //filter nest array by the selected var on user second slection
    var filteredOwner =nest3.filter(function(d) {
      return d.key == selectedDate})[0]

      //extract value of second nested array
    var nest4 = filteredOwner.values;
    //clean second media selection before appending the new selected media
    var clean = d3.select("#owner").selectAll("select").remove();

    //create the secod select
    var date = d3.select("#owner")
        date
        .append("select")
        .attr('class', "custom-select")
        .attr('id', 'media_owner')
        .selectAll("option")
        .data(nest4)
        .enter()
        .append("option")
        .attr("value", function(d){return d.key;})
        .text(function(d){return d.key;})


})}
```

Now I'm struggling on how to populate all divs on load. As you can see my script populate different divs onchange depending from the first dropdown but I also want everything to be pouplated on load

does anyone knows how to manage it?

many thanks